# Rename Rank and Retrieve Cluster Name

Tags: solr, rename, ibm-watson, retrieve-and-rank

So I created a Solr Cluster via the Rank and Retrieve web tooling. The name of the cluster is similar to "Cluster Client".
Problem here is the online tooling allows names with blanks.

Now, after training the ranker I want to access the query interface via API. The call goes similar to:
http://gateway.watsonplatform.net/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/solr_clusters/CLUSTER_ID/solr/CLUSTER_NAME/select?q=QUERY&wt=json

So problem is now: my CLUSTER_NAME has spaces in there.
First thought: escape it with "%20" or "+" => doesn't work :(

**So the question is now:
 
a) How can I query my cluster?

b) If that is not possible: How can I rename my cluster, remove the space, so I can access it?**

Comment: Do you mean the collection name? It should be clusterid/solr/collectionname. Maybe you're using the name of the wrong thing in your URL?

Comment: That was the solution! Thanks, wrong parameter. :(

Answer (score 1):

You should use the collection name and NOT the cluster name as a parameter.
See https://stackoverflow.com/users/477/dalelane comment above.